# Filling 3D numpy array with one variable dimension

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I would like to fill a 3D numpy array which has dimension (?, 100, 100). The first dimension will range between 500 and 1000 but is not known beforehand. I could use the append method, but this is slow.

Is there another posibility to create such a 3D numpy array where the first dimension is not known beforehand? The numpy array is filled using a for loop.

Second, let's assume I have the following two numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(30, 100, 100))
arr2 = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(50, 100, 100))
```

How can I concatenate `arr1` and `arr2` along the first dimension so that the resulting array has shape (80, 100, 100)?

Comment: `np.concatenate((arr1, arr2), axis=0)`

Comment: If you need to define the component arrays in a loop, collect them in a list, with `list.append`.  Then do one `concatenate` (or maybe `vstack` or `stack`) at the end.

Comment: @hpaulj I have collected the arrays in a list, i.e. I have a list containing 2D arrays. When I use vstack or stack or concatenate over the list, then the arrays are concatenated either on the first or second dimension which I don't want. What I want is that when arrays in list have dimensions (a,b), I would like to get a resulting arrays with dimensions (n,a,b). Is this possible?

Comment: `np.stack` uses a new dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the first question, I always use np.empty and np.append methodes which are totaly fine.

```
arr = np.empty((0, 100, 100), int)
arr = np.append(arr,x,axis=0)
```

about the second question, append works well again:

```
arr3  = np.append(arr1, arr2, axis=0)
```

also 'concatenate' is usable:

```
arr3  = np.concatenate((arr1, arr2), axis=0)
```

Comment: `np.append` takes 2 arguments, tweaks them a bit, and then calls `concatenate((arg1, arg2), axis=axis)`.  It's ok when used once, but too many users try to use it in a loop.   It's better to collect a list of arrays (list append is more efficient) and do one concatenate at the end.  Plus defining that initial "empty" array is tricky for most beginners.

Comment: About the storing data in a list and then make array from that I do agree that it is much faster.